# NameError: name 'temp_output' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have the following code :

```
import os
import time

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

temp_sensor = '/sys/bus/w1/devices/28-0000095ea98a/w1_slave'

def Temp_Raw():
    f = open(temp_sensor, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines
def Read_Temp():
    lines = Temp_Raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
         time.sleep(0.2)
         lines = Temp_Raw()
```

here is where the problem comes in:(temp_output)

```
def Read_Temp():
        lines = Temp_Raw()
        while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
             time.sleep(0.2)
             lines = Temp_Raw()
        temp_output = lines[1].find('t=')
        if temp_output != -1:
            temp_sting = lines[1].strip()[temp_output+2:]
            temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0
            return temp_c, temp_f
while True:
     print(Read_Temp())
     time.sleep(1)
```

I am trying to program a temperature sensor and when I run the following code this error appears :

```
NameError: name 'temp_output' is not defined
```

I check the code multiple times and did not find what was wrong.Could anyone please help me out on what I have to do ? Thanks

Comment: The code you posted doesn't throw that error. It gives me a `NameError: name 'temp_string' is not defined`.

Comment: For line `temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0`, a line before you have `temp_sting` instead of `temp_string`, not sure if it is the same variable you want to use.

Comment: @zana recheck the error it should be temp_string not defined

Comment: Oh sorry that was a typo 'temp_string' is what i intended to write. The Error is still the same :/ here is the full error:  Traceback : File "home/pi/TemperatureSensor.py", line 28, in <module> print(Read_Temp()) File "home/pi/TemperatureSensor.py", line 21, in Read_Temp() if temp_output !=1 NameError: name 'temp_output' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where this error comes from, however, more likely an error will occur due to your misspelling of "temp_string" as "temp_sting", which will of course throw a `NameError` later

Comment: Thanks ..But i wrote it wrong by mistake on here ..on the actual code that i have on python i wrote it right